# Python: How to solve the issue : 'badly formed hexadecimal UUID string' in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, auto-generate

I have created 'post' model in which I included 'post_id' as the primary key field. When I am trying to create a post, it is raising an error: 'badly formed hexadecimal UUID string'. I would appreciate helping me in solve this.

Here's my code.

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default='uuid.uuid4', editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    To = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"post_id": self.post_id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-Time"]
```

views.py:

```
def post_create(request):

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get("post_id"))
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "loggedin_load/post_load.html", context)
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a custom `post_id`? By default, Django models contain an `id` and `pk` field. You can use either one of those to track a `post_id`.

Comment: What's the full error you're getting?

Comment: Try without quotes, `default=uuid.uuid4`

Comment: @Rohan If I am removing quotes, it raising a name error: name 'uuid' isn't defined.

Comment: @jape in my def __str__(self): i wanted to return it as return self.post_id, I couldn't able to do it with one it was created by default. If possible, How can achieve this with by default auotcreated 'id'?

Comment: Have you imported uuid?

Comment: If uuid isn't found, then you should import it, obviously. That is fairly basic Python.

Comment: I did this : from uuid import UUID. Is this wrong?

Comment: `uuid` is the module, the way your using it you just need `import uuid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the module and not use quotes around `'uuid.uuid4'`.

It should be somewhat like:

```
import uuid  # The uuid module
class Post(models.Model):

    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)  # using the function uuid4 on the module
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    To = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"post_id": self.post_id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-Time"]
```

N.B I've not tested the above code, and I agree with some of the comments you shouldn't need a UUID for the post_id. Without knowing more I couldn't help further.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Post(models.Model):
    # Instead of default, maybe do null=True to take old entries into account?
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # You may want to reconsider the naming of the "To" field
    # to avoid capital letters and built-in functions
    To = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    # You can remove this with the decorator above
    # def __unicode__(self):
        # return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id  # acts as your post_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"post_id": self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-Time"]
```

Whenever an object is created, it will automatically be assigned an id, which will populate your `__unicode__`, `__str__`, and `get_absolute_url`.