# Click on row in django-tables2 to take me to another table?

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I basically want to click on a row or linked element and take me to another filtered table.

For instance, let's say I have a table of genres:

```
Romance
Horror
Comedy
```

I click on Romance, and then I want a list of all the romance books. How might I do this with django-tables2?

How do I get what the user clicked on in my django table?

I tried to use
table.py

```
class GenreTable(tables.Table):
     genre = tables.LinkColumn('books_genre_table')
     class Meta: ...
```

This doesn't work because I can't pass the data and filter it to make a table in the next view/html 'books_genre_table.html'

EDIT: I already have a detail page for genres that is different than this page that I want to create. Furthermore, I want to filter the data in a new way that does not need to be saved as a detail page with a 'pk'. I just want to have all of these go to one url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `genre` URL like this:

```
path('some_path/<int:pk>/', genre_book_view, name='books_genre_table')
```

and have a view like this(here I will be using [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) to fetch books from genre):

```
def genre_book(request, pk):
     # will be using genre here to fetch all the books
     genre = Genre.objects.get(pk=pk)
     context = {
         'books': genre.book_set.all()  # using reverse relation to get the books
     }
     return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Then you can link your view like this:

```
class GenreTable(tables.Table):
     genre = tables.LinkColumn('books_genre_table', args=[A('pk')])
     class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have a detail page for genres that is different than this. I want to filter the data in a new way that does not need to be saved as a detail page with a pk. I just want to have all of these go the same url.

Comment: I think this should work, but I'm still getting an error: NoReverseMatch

Comment: Sorry the error message is: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string. My pk is a uuid code. I get this error when I try to render the table.

Comment: sorry to say, the error message is not enough to determine why this problem is occurring. Did you try with path `some_path/<uuid:pk>/`? Also this post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459942/python-how-to-solve-the-issue-badly-formed-hexadecimal-uuid-string-in-djang. If its not sufficient, then please consider asking a new question, please provide a link to me as well, I will try my best to resolve it. thanks

Comment: here is the quesition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130764/badly-formed-hexadecimal-uuid-error-string-for-a-uuid-primary-key