# badly formed hexadecimal UUID error string for a UUID primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, uuid, django-tables2

I'm trying to get my table to load, but am getting this error, most likely because my primary key is a uuid.

Here is my url paths.

```
path('results/', views.results, name='results'),
path('results/<uuid:pk>/', views.genre_book, name='books_genre_table'),
```

Here is my views.py
If there is one observation, we load the price table. If not, then we load a table with service descriptions. The user can then pick the service they are most interested and click through to the price table for that service. This is not working. The first view "results" works, but the second view book_genre does not.

```
 def results(request):
    query_string = ''
    found_entries = None
    if ('s' in request.GET) and request.GET['s'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['s']
        entry_query = get_query(query_string,['service__desc_us', 'com_desc'])
        _objs = Price.objects.filter(entry_query).values('service__join').distinct()
        num_obj = Price.objects.filter(entry_query).values('service__join').distinct().count()
        if num_obj == 1:
            Price_objs = Price.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by("price_offer")
            table = PriceTable(Price_objs)
            RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
        if num_obj > 1:
            model = Service
            entry_query = get_query(query_string,['desc_us', 'price__com_desc'])
            serv_obj = Service.objects.filter(entry_query).distinct()
            table = ServiceTable(serv_obj)
            RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'results.html', {'table': table})

def genre_book(request, pk):
     serv_obj = Service.objects.get(pk=pk)
     price_obj = Price.objects.filter(service=serv_obj).values("join")
     table = PriceTable(price_obj)
     RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
     return render(request, 'results.html', {'table': table})
```

Here is my tables.py file

```
class PriceTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
        sequence = ('service', 'price_offer')
        exclude = ('priceid', 'com_desc', "comments")
        attrs = {"class": "darkblue"}

class ServiceTable(tables.Table):
    desc_us = tables.LinkColumn('books_genre_table', args=[A('pk')])
    class Meta:
        model = Service
      ...
```

Here is my model for service:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    serviceid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
      help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database', editable=False)
    desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True)
    join = models.IntegerField(default= 10000) #foreign key with price model

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['serviceid']

    def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.desc_us

class Price(models.Model):
  priceid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
  com_desc = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
  service = models.ForeignKey("Service", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  price_offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

  class Meta:
       ordering =['service']

  def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.service.desc_us} ({self.price_offer})'
```

FULL ERROR printout

```
Error during template rendering
In template 
projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/bootstrap4.html, error at line 26

badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
16                              {{ column.header }}
17                          {% endif %}
18                      </th>
19                  {% endfor %}
20                  </tr>
21                  </thead>
22              {% endif %}
23              {% endblock table.thead %}
24              {% block table.tbody %}
25                  <tbody {{ table.attrs.tbody.as_html }}>
 #below row highlighted
26                  {% for row in table.paginated_rows %}
27                      {% block table.tbody.row %}
28                      <tr scope="row" {{ row.attrs.as_html }}>
29                          {% for column, cell in row.items %}
30                              <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{% if column.localize == None %}{{ cell }}{% else %}{% if column.localize %}{{ cell|localize }}{% else %}{{ cell|unlocalize }}{% endif %}{% endif %}</td>
31                          {% endfor %}
32                      </tr>
33                      {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
34                  {% empty %}
35                      {% if table.empty_text %}
36                      {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
```

Here is the beginning of the traceback:

```
File "projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_tables2/rows.py" in __len__
  335.         length = len(self.data)

File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  63.         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):

File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in apply_converters
  1009.                     value = converter(value, expression, connection)

File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py" in convert_uuidfield_value
  263.             value = uuid.UUID(value)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/uuid.py" in __init__
  160.                 raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')

Exception Type: ValueError at /results/
Exception Value: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

Here is what pulls up this error in the source code, uuid.py

```
    if hex is not None:
        hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
        hex = hex.strip('{}').replace('-', '')
        if len(hex) != 32:
            raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
        int = int_(hex, 16)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: What's the URL look like? My guess is the path your building doesn't have the hyphens (hexadecimal), but the (pk=pk) in the get requires the UUID to be a str representation (with hyphens).

Comment: @Iain added trace; @Trent; no idea what the URL looks like, it doesn't seem to make it that far.

Comment: @Trent, if that is the case how do I fix that?

Comment: change the <uuid:pk> to (?P<pk>[a-z0-9\-]+) - so it doesn't try to validate it. Let the query do that and catch it in code.

Comment: @Trent, it doesn't seem to fix it. Any other ideas?

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error? Are you saying you go to results, which correctly renders, then you click on a link for books_genre_table, which tries to render that template but gets the error?

Comment: And can you show the full definitions for PriceTable and ServiceTable?

Comment: @Daniel, added the PriceTable and ServiceTable is the same, etc with Service model. They both work, when I change the primary key to something else from the UUID.

Comment: We need to see the code for the a href where the link is being built. Without knowing what the URL formed looks like; we may well be chasing a red herring

Comment: @Trent, so I'm using django-tables2. There is no href. The line desc_us = tables.LinkColumn('books_genre_table', args=[A('pk')]) should take care of that. I could also add my project to github.

Comment: @Daniel could I add my project to github and could you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: if it's not sensitive, add it to github