# Complex name as primary key django error "NoReverseMatch"

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I have complex names as the primary key, like "Service books\ PS 35 fianto". Django doesn't like them, so I get the NoReverseMatch error.

Here is my url path:

```
path('results/<str:pk>/', views.genre_book, name='books_genre_table'),
```

My primary key for the model is a a TextField.

```
desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True, unique=True)
```

Here is my error thread:

```
Reverse for 'books_genre_table' with arguments '('Cta book Win / out Compatability ',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
```

This url is for a table with that unique service. However, the URL will not match. The underlying code works.

Heres my table.py

```
class ServiceTable(tables.Table):
    desc_us = tables.LinkColumn('books_genre_table', args=[A('pk')])
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
        sequence = ('desc_us')
        exclude =('serviceid', 'price')
        attrs = {"class": "darkblue"}
```

Comment: Firstly, don't do this. Your primary key should not be a text field; ideally it should be an opaque value. But even if for some reason you want to have your pk like this, don't use it in a URL; use a slug.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? How to create a slug. My primary key was originally a uuid, but could not fix the error below. This model does not have that many fields.

Comment: This error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130764/badly-formed-hexadecimal-uuid-error-string-for-a-uuid-primary-key

Comment: @Daniel can you create a slug without rebuilding the table for the model?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "rebuilding". You can use migrations to add a slug field, just like any other field. But addressing the issue with UUIDs would be preferable.

Comment: @Daniel, spent a day looking at it and was unable to solve, any suggestions?